# Pgbackrest connection to Patroni cluster with HAProxy (VIP)

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I have Patroni cluster with:

- 1 VIP
- 3 nodes HAProxy
- 3 nodes PostgreSQL Patroni
- 3 nodes etcd

And dedicated pgbackrest server, from which I want to connect to Patroni cluster and take backups. But I don't want to connect to physical servers, because I've configured backup standby, and so after switchover or failovers, I must to change pgbackrest.conf file each time.
Is it acceptable to connect through HAProxy VIP to Patroni cluster from pgbackrest.conf?

pgbackrest.conf:

```
[global]
#repo1-path=/var/lib/pgbackrest
repo1-host-user=postgres
repo1-host-type=ssh
log-level-console=debug
log-level-file=detail
compress=n
start-fast=y
stop-auto=y

[pg_test]
repo1-path=/var/lib/pgbackrest/pg_test
pg1-host=VIP
pg1-host-user=pgbackrest
pg1-path=/opt/postgres/data/
pg1-port=5000
pg2-host=VIP
pg2-host-user=pgbackrest
pg2-path=/opt/postgres/data/
pg2-port=5001
backup-standby=y
archive-async=y
process-max=2
repo1-retention-full=2
```

My patroni parameters:

```
parameters:
    archive_command: pgbackrest --stanza=pg_test archive-push %p
    archive_mode: true
    autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor: 0.05
    autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor: 0.05
    checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
    checkpoint_timeout: 15 min
    effective_cache_size: 11 GB
    effective_io_concurrency: 100
    huge_pages: false
    maintenance_work_mem: 320 MB
    max_connections: 1000;
    max_parallel_maintenance_workers: 4
    max_parallel_workers: 8
    max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 4
    max_wal_senders: 10
    max_wal_size: 1024 MB
    max_worker_processes: 8
    min_wal_size: 512 MB
    parallel_leader_participation: true
    random_page_cost: 1.25
    shared_buffers: 4096 MB
    work_mem: 32 MB
```

And this is error I'm getting when creating stanza:

```
-------------------PROCESS START-------------------
2024-03-18 08:41:49.679 P00   INFO: stanza-create command begin 2.50: --exec-id=1598083-c6b0e543 --log-level-console=info --log-level-file=detail --pg1-host=VIP_adress --pg2-host=VIP_adress --pg1-host-user=pgbackrest --pg2-host-user=pgbackrest --pg1-path=/opt/postgres/data/ --pg2-path=/opt/postgres/data/ --pg1-port=5000 --pg2-port=5001 --repo1-host-type=ssh --repo1-path=/var/lib/pgbackrest/pg_test --stanza=pg_test
2024-03-18 08:41:50.055 P00   WARN: unable to check pg1: [OptionRequiredError] remote-0 process on 'VIP_adress' terminated unexpectedly [37]: ERROR: [037]: stanza-create command requires option: pg2-path
                                           HINT: does this stanza exist?
2024-03-18 08:41:50.292 P00   WARN: unable to check pg2: [OptionRequiredError] remote-0 process on 'VIP_adress' terminated unexpectedly [37]: ERROR: [037]: stanza-create command requires option: pg2-path
                                           HINT: does this stanza exist?
2024-03-18 08:41:50.292 P00  ERROR: [056]: unable to find primary cluster - cannot proceed
                                    HINT: are all available clusters in recovery?
2024-03-18 08:41:50.292 P00   INFO: stanza-create command end: aborted with exception [056]
```

Comment: Sure, why not? But you could also use connection strings that specify [multiple hosts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-MULTIPLE-HOSTS) and use `target_session_attrs` to get to the right one.

Comment: My question is that can I connect pgbackrest via VIP, as I connect to the database in Patroni cluster with a haproxy, or do I need to connect directly to the database?

Comment: What could keep you from connecting to the database via the virtual IP address?

Comment: After installing pgbackrest on HAProxy servers and trying connection to virtual IP, I'm getting errors:
`unable to check pg1: [DbConnectError] raised from remote-0 ssh protocol on 'VIP': unable to connect to 'dbname='postgres' port=5000': connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5000" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

Comment: You should add that to the question, together with your pgBackRest configuration.